# Have anyone found Product Tags feature Extension for Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product-tag

I want Product tag feature extension in magento2 like magento1.

Have anyone implemented before?

I know it's not exist in core magento2.

Comment: Please explain bit more for what purpose you want extension?

Comment: Because i want to convert my magento1 site same to same in magento2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check below link for Product Tags extension. If it can help you.

https://codecanyon.net/item/product-tags-for-magento-2/19605902

Comment: Welcome @Rutvee

Answer (score 2):

Check this extension for Product Tags

https://www.webinse.com/store/magento2-product-tags

Comment: Yes i have checked that but it's not met with my requirements.